# Treize, quatorze, quinze, seize

Tags: nombres

French has specific words for 13, 14, 15, 16 when other neighboring languages (e.g. English, Dutch) have specific words only up to 12 and regular forms for 13–19. Is this phenomenon specific to French? If so, how did it come about? Or does French share this characteristic with other related languages?

---

Comment se fait-il que le français ait des mots spécifiques pour 13, 14, 15, 16 alors que d'autres langages voisins (comme l'anglais et le néerlandais) n'en ont que jusqu'à 12 et ont des formes régulières pour 13 à 19 ? Si ce phénomène est particulier au français, comment est-il advenu ? Ou alors est-ce que d'autres langues ont cette caractéristique ?

Comment: That would be a good question for the proposed [Linguistics Q&A](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6673/linguistics?referrer=XIQazUPS3qxMg1X13CJ1vg2)!

Comment: Il y a peut-être un lien entre le fait qu'il a été "décidé" la composition des nombres change entre 16 et 17, et [entre 60 et 70](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/989/442).

Comment: Voir aussi des questions similaires pour [l'anglais](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/7281), [l'espagnol](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3969), [l'italien](http://italian.stackexchange.com/q/1528), [le portugais](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/4). Et [sur l'incohérence des langues romanes](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/6380).

Comment: @Gilles: Jetez un coup d'oeil à cette [réponse](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/9811/707).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je crois qu'il n'y a pas vraiment de raison pour cela.

Le latin compose les nombres de onze jusque 19. Les formes simples proviennent de contraction de ces mots composés. Les différentes langues ont coupé la numération simple à différent nombre. Comme le montre [cette page](http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/curiosites/dix-sept.html), le français, l'occitan, l'italien et le catalan s'arrêtent au 16, mais l'espagnol, le galicien et le portugais à 15. Seul le roumain possède une numération de 11 à 19 entièrement composée.

Pourquoi les transitions se sont faites à un nombre particulier... peut-être parce que la prononciation devenait compliquée? "setpze", "huitze"?

Comment: Il y a des fautes pour l'italien dans cette page. Nous disons "dieci", "undici" et "diciannove", et non "deci", "undeci" et "diciannouve".