# D'où viennent soixante-dix et quatre-vingts (plutôt que septante et huitante) ?

Tags: histoire, nombres

Pourquoi est-ce qu'en français on dit « quatre-vingts » plutôt que quelque chose qui se base sur dix, comme « huitante » ou « octante » ?

Même chose pour *soixante-dix / septante* et *quatre-vingt-dix / nonante*.

D'où vient cette façon de compter ?

Est-ce que les autres mots (comme *septante*, *huitante*, *nonante*) sont reconnus, acceptés ? Si j'utilise *huitante* à l'académie française, est-ce que ce sera accepté ?

Comment: Voir https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/w/index.php?title=Système_vicésimal#Histoire. J'ai entendu dire que cet usage en français était un reste de langues celtiques. À vérifier.

Comment: Related question : [Quelles parties du monde francophone continuent à utiliser les nombres réformés pour dénombrer au-delà de 69?](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/187/82) and [potential answer](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/187/quelles-parties-du-monde-francophone-continuent-a-utiliser-les-nombres-reformes-p/197#197)

Comment: En Suisse Romande (région francophone de la Suisse). le septante, huitante, nonante, nous paraissent plus "normal et logique", de dire par exemple, 898 : huit cent nonant huit, que huit cent quatre vingt dix huit.
En appliquant cette logique de vingtaines aux centaines, imaginez ce que cela ferait sur 998 : quatre deux cent dix quatre vint dix neuf !!!!!! au lieu de : neuf cent nonante neuf !!!!!!! pour nous , Romands, ce serait inconcevable et illogique autant que pour vous ... qui a tort, qui a raison, c'est pas si important, mais la logique devait primer ! un Vaudois

Comment: @user7993 Pourtant un certains nombre de Romands utilisent quatre-vingt.

Comment: pourquoi un système décimal ? ... car on compte sur ses dix doigts ! pourquoi un système vicésimal ? ... car, en marchant pieds nus et plutôt dans la position du singe, on compte sur ses vingt doigts !! De là, à penser que les français sont encore un peu préhistoriques ... il n'y a qu'un pas ...

Comment: Je suis aussi partisan du "septante" ou "nonante". D'ailleurs lorsque l'on parle d'une personne ayant 70 ans, on dit un "septuagénaire" et non un "soixante-dix-agénaire" non? Même chose pour une personne ayant 90 ans, on dit un "nonagénaire" et non pas un "quatre-vingt-dix-agénaire". Quand est-ce que l'on rétablira une façon de dire les chiffres logiquement en France?

Answer (score 46):

Les Romains comptaient par dizaines, donc le français compte étymologiquement en système [décimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_names#10:_decimal) (par 10). Par contre les Celtes (et quelques autres peuples d'Europe) comptent en système [vicésimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_names#20:_vigesimal) (par 20). Au fil du temps, les deux systèmes se sont affrontés, et [ce ne sont pas toujours les mêmes qui ont gagné partout](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/187/quelles-parties-du-monde-francophone-continuent-a-utiliser-les-nombres-reformes-p). Le français est d'ailleurs une des rares langues européennes qui a gardé des traces du système vicésimal (le [mannois](http://www.sf.airnet.ne.jp/~ts/language/number/manx.html) et le [basque](http://www.buber.net/Basque/Euskara/zenbak.html) sont restés vicésimaux ; le [gaélique](http://www.sf.airnet.ne.jp/~ts/language/number/scots_gaelic.html) et le [gallois](http://www.sf.airnet.ne.jp/~ts/language/number/modern_welsh.html) sont passés en décimal, encore que ce soit récent pour le [gallois](http://www.sf.airnet.ne.jp/~ts/language/number/traditional_welsh.html) ; le [breton](http://www.sf.airnet.ne.jp/~ts/language/number/breton.html) a comme le français un système mixte, au moins dans certains dialectes).

Au Moyen Âge, en France, le système vicésimal est plus utilisé que le système décimal : on disait plutôt « *vint et dis* » (30), « *deux vins* » (40), « *deux vins et dis* » (50), « *trois vins* » (60), etc. Les formes décimales dérivées du latin populaire existaient aussi, en particulier *[huitante](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/huitante)*. À la fin du Moyen Âge (peut être sous influence italienne, mais c'est une conjecture), les formes décimales sont devenues dominantes : trente, quarante, soixante, … La forme savante *[octante](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/octante)* est apparue au XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle.

Les nouvelles formes ont pris inégalement suivant les nombres. Le [dictionnaire de l'Académie française](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionnaire_de_l%E2%80%99Acad%C3%A9mie_fran%C3%A7aise) de 1694 indique (citations partielles) :

> - Septante. Nombre composé de sept dixaines. Il n'a guere d'usage que dans les supputations d'Arithmetique. [T.2 p.467]
> - Huitante ou plutost octante. Nombre contenant huit fois dix. Il n'est point en usage dans le discours commun, on dit, *Quatre-vingts*, mais on s'en sert dans les supputations d'Arithmetique. [T.1 p.574]
> - Octante. Quatre-vingt. Il n'a guere d'usage que dans les supputations d'Arithmetique. [T.1 p.574]
> - Nonante. Nombre composé de neuf dixaines. On se sert de ce terme dans l'Arithmetique ; mais dans le discours ordinaire on dit Quatre-vingt-dix. [T.1 p.117]

Au passage, le Dictionnaire épelle 70 « soixante & dix ». Les éditions suivantes considèrent « septante », « octante » et « nonante » comme viellis. [Littré](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littr%C3%A9), vers 1870, déclare (citations partielles) :

> - [Septante](http://artflx.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/dicos/pubdico1look.pl?strippedhw=septante) : soixante et dix (il a vielli). Septante, quoique bien préférable à soixante-dix, puisqu'il est dans l'analogie de quarante, cinquante, soixante, n'est guère usité que par des personnes appartenant au midi de la France. Il serait à désirer qu'il revînt dans l'usage et chassât soixante-dix.
> - [Huitante](http://artflx.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/dicos/pubdico1look.pl?strippedhw=huitante) : Quatre-vingts.
> - [Octante](http://artflx.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/dicos/pubdico1look.pl?strippedhw=octante) : Quatre-vingts. Terme vieilli, et c'est dommage, dans la langue littéraire ; il est resté en usage dans le parler du Midi.
> - [Nonante](http://artflx.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/dicos/pubdico1look.pl?strippedhw=nonante) : Nom de nombre cardinal composé de neuf dizaines. Nonante a vieilli, et c'est dommage ; il est resté très usité en Suisse, en Savoie et dans le midi de la France.

Ce que je trouve le plus curieux est la forme mixte *[soixante-dix](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/soixante-dix)*, qui existait déjà en ancien français (attestée au XII<sup>e</sup> siècle).

Comment: Il est ironique que "huitante" est considéré comme la terme "vieilli"; on peux penser qu'au fil du temps la système peut devenir plus logique comme les nombres jusqu'à "soixante" !  Pour moi, le "quatre-vingt" est la terme vieilli.

Comment: @Jez « Vieilli » signifie qu'on ne l'utilise plus (English dictionaries use *dated*). Ça qualifie l'usage, pas la formation. En France, *quatre-vingt* est le seul terme qui existe encore ; *huitante* et autres étaient déjà vieillis il y a un siècle et ont aujourd'hui disparu.

Comment: La Belgique est oubliée. En Belgique, on utilise aussi *quatre-vingts*, mais on n'utilise pas *soixante-dix*. On dit *septante*.

Comment: et on dit nonante pour 90

Comment: "*Four score and 7 years ago...*"

Comment: Il me semble que les suisse-français utilisent _octante_, que j'aime beaucoup.

Comment: @YSC [Quelles parties du monde francophone continuent à utiliser les nombres réformés pour dénombrer au-delà de 69?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/187/quelles-parties-du-monde-francophone-continuent-%c3%a0-utiliser-les-nombres-r%c3%a9form%c3%a9s) D'après mes source, c'est en perte de vitesse.

Answer (score 8):

Grevisse dit seulement « *Quatre-vingt* et d'une façon générale les numéraux allant de soixante et onze à quatre-vingt-dix-neuf (usités là où on ignore *septante* et *nonante*) appartiennent à la numérotation **vicésimale**, c'est-à-dire *par vingt*. On lui attribue souvent une origine gauloise. » sans en dire plus sur cette origine.

Il y a d'autres restes de cette numérotation sortis d'usage au cours du temps. *Six-vingt* est resté apparemment le plus longtemps (on le trouve dans le *Bourgeois gentilhomme* p.e.).  Il y a aussi les *Quinze-Vingts*, un hôpital de Paris, mais sous forme figée.

Georges Ifrah, dans son *Histoire universelle des chiffres* analyse plus en détail la numérotation dans les langues indo-européennes et les restes de numérotation vicésimale chez celles-ci (en anglais, l'usage de score p.e.). Son hypothèse est que les Indo-Européens lorsqu'ils se sont installés dans les régions allant de la Scandinavie au nord de l'Espagne y on trouvé des populations indigènes utilisant ce système. Il compte comme indice confortant son hypothèse le fait que les Basques comptent encore ainsi jusqu'à 99.

Comment: « On lui attribue une origine gauloise » certainement parce que c'est assez courant dans les langues celtiques, le breton naturel l'utilise généralement, le gallois aussi, et les autres sûrement.

Comment: N.B. Le centre hospitalier national d’ophtalmologie des *Quinze-Vingts* sa particularité : http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B4pital_des_Quinze-Vingts

Answer (score 5):

La césure avec le système 'vicésimal'  (trois vins et dis) n'est pas clairement identifiée dans les sources que je peux trouver.

Le TLF cite :

> MEIGRET, Traité de gramm., éd. F. J. Hausmann, p. 42: ,,nous avons une autre manière de compter plus reçue et approuvée: par laquelle, en poursuivant le nombre, nous disons soixante et dix pour septante``.

Les autres formes septante et nonante sont courantes (et officielles) en Belgique et en Suisse. En revanche, octante ne l'est pas et certains Suisses utilisent huitante.

L'Académie Française à pendant un moment préféré aussi septante etc, mais ils sont maintenant décrits comme d'un usage vieilli.

Voir aussi:

- http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/70_(nombre)#Linguistique
- http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/soixante-dix

Answer (score 0):

Ce qui est curieux, c'est que pour une personne qui a nonante ans on parle pourtant bien d'un nonagénaire et non pas d'un *quatre-vingt-dix-génaire* !!  (idem pour le septuagénaire qui serait un *soixante-dix-génaire*...)
Les Français ont donc quand-même gardé un peu de bon sens ;-).

PS: Les Allemands inversent bien les dizaines et les unité en 20 et 99 (un et vingt pour 21).

Les plus logiques sont encore les anglophones (hormis le 11 et le 12).

Comment: La logique des anglophones reste relative, on dit bien hundred pour cent, mais on utilise cent partout ailleurs: percent, fifty cent etc

Answer (score -2):

En Belgique, on compte comme ceci: soixante, septante, quatre-vingts et nonante. Ce qui est ironique, c'est que les Français croient être plus modernes que nous avec leurs soixante-dix et quatre-vingts-dix alors que votre article montre bien cet archaïsme est typique d'un peuple coincé par son histoire. Une autre ironie est qu'aujourd'hui pour parler du département de Seine-Saint-Denis (où des constructions doivent être érigées pour les jeux olympiques de 2024) ils parlent du "neuf trois" pour ne pas devoir dire le quatre-vingt treize alors qu'un Belge dirait le "nonante trois".

Comment: En quoi cela répond-il à la question?

Comment: En plus de ne pas répondre à la question, c'est condescendant, si on suit cette logique les Belges sont aussi des arriérés vis à vis des Valaisans (Suisse) puisque ces derniers disent huitante et pas quatre-vingts. Le neuf-trois c'est une expression *du bled* pour dire quatre-vingts treize, personne n'utiliserais neuf trois dans un contexte courant ou professionnel.