# Quelle différence entre mille neuf cent et dix-neuf cent

Tags: expressions, nombres

Comment se fait-il que pour les nombres de 1000 à 1999 on puisse les prononcer des deux manières suivantes :

- **dix-neuf cents ...**
- **mille neuf cents ...**

d'où vient cette différence ?

Et pourquoi n'est ce pas appliqué (tout du moins pas à ma connaissance) sur les nombres supérieurs à 2000 (exception faite de la devinette : "Vincent mit l'âne dans le pré, et s'en vint dans l'autre. Combien y'a t'il d'ânes dans les prés ?") ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Je pense que c'est un reste d'usage de la [numération vigésimale](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/989/dou-viennent-soixante-dix-et-quatre-vingt-plutot-que-septante-et-huitante), comme *soixante-dix* et *quatre-vingts-dix*. Si aujourd'hui on ne l'utilise plus que pour les années, et seulement à l'oral, l'usage était autrefois plus répandu. Voir par exemple des citations rassemblées par [Grevisse](http://books.google.fr/books?id=l2hcAAAAMAAJ&q=%22dix+neuf+cents%22&dq=%22dix+neuf+cents%22&hl=fr) :

> dix-neuf cents feux (Balzac, 1833)
>   dix-neuf cents écus (Cocteau, 1949)

Comment: Et je rajouterais que même l'usage de "dix-neuf cent" pour les années à l'oral a tendance à devenir de plus en plus rare

Answer (score 7):

On utilisera *dix-neuf cents* pour les dates plutôt dans un français parlé. C'est plus une commodité du langage qu'une règle : *dix-neuf cent trente* sonne mieux que *mille neuf cent trente* et cela dépendra des personnes...

Cette utilisation est [mentionnée](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nombres_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Centaines_vig.C3.A9simales) sur wikipedia.

Sinon, note qu'on met un trait d'union sur tous les nombres inférieurs à cent.
Donc : *quatre-vingt-dix-neuf*, *cent trente* et *vingt-deux mille quatre cent quarante-quatre*.