# The difference between pronunciations of 8 in "1835" and" 1928"

Tags: prononciation, nombres

I realized that the pronunciation of 8 in (say)1835, when 8 is adjacent to "mille", is different  from its pronunciation in (say) 1928, when 8 lies in the first digit:

"Mille oui cent trente cinque"
and

"Mille neuf cent vingt witt"

Am I correct? Or I am mistaken?
Why do not we say "mille witt cent trwnt cinque"?

Your answer is very appreciated.

Comment: *Huit* prononcé 'oui-te' (wuit) est entendu dans l’est de la France. particulièrement dans les Vosges. La prononciation correcte : *u-i* s’il est suivi d’une consonne, sinon  *u-i-t'*.

Comment: @Personne et aussi en français de Belgique dont c'est une caractéristique très reconnaissable.

Comment: A side note; you could tell 18-35 if you are having difficulty with the other pronounciation. So it would be heard like, dix-huit trente cinq. It's often singued that way in song for date, but you will never see that wrote that way as it's not the correct's way.

Comment: @yagmoth555 I have never heard *dix-huit trente-cinq* in France to state a date. On the other hand *dix-huit **cent** trente-cinq* is still common. https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/quelle-diff%c3%a9rence-entre-mille-neuf-cent-et-dix-neuf-cent

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We always pronounce the `t` at the end of *huit*, except when it is followed by a word beginning with a consonant.

- 1828 : mille huit cent vingt-huit : we don't pronounce the former “t” because there is a consonant after (i.e. “c”) but we pronounce the latter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To be honnest I hear the following:"mi-lui-cent-trente-cinqu. Is it near to the true pronunciation?

Comment: @AliTaghavi: Yes, it is.

Comment: A notable exception: when counting, or in a count-down, we prononce the 't' even before another consonant: in "Cinq six sept huit neuf dix", or "dix neuf huit sept six". Also, of course, in front of a "h muet" as in "huit heures".

Comment: @Evargalo: I would note that in a count/count-down there's a notable slight pause before the next number. If you have a pause (dot, comma, colon, semi-colon), then the next word doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

The final consonant of *huit* is often dropped when it is part of the phrasing *mille-huit-cent* simply because it rolls off the tongue better, but it would not be a mistake to pronounce it.

This elision can also happen when the word *huit* is placed before any word that begins with a consonant other than *h*, or when the word *huit* is followed by %. Examples from the [Office Québécois de la Langue Française](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3149):

> Éric commencera ses cours le 8 septembre. [ɥitsɛptãbʀ] (uit-sèp-tan-br) ou [ɥisɛptãbʀ] (ui-sèp-tan-br)

> Le sondage indique que 88 % des personnes interrogées ont accès à Internet à la maison ou au travail. [katʀevẽɥipuʀsã] (ka-tre-vin-ui-pour-san) ou [katʀevẽɥitpuʀsã] (ka-tre-vin-uit-pour-san)

In my dialect of French spoken in the metropolitan area of Québec, this elision can also be applied to other digits, though is less common to do so in formal contexts. You can read more about it on the [OQLF's website](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=1&Th_id=306&niveau=). Judging from people's comments, that is not a thing in France.

- *mille-cin-cent*
- *mille-sè-cent*
- *mille-neu-cent*

Note that the pronunciation of the rest of the digit doesn't change. Even if you drop the `t` in *huit*, you should pronounce *hui* all the same. In the question, `hui` was approximated as `oui` and `wi`, but neither are exact. You'll probably just get yourself more confused if you try to rewrite French words as if they were made of English sounds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To be honnest I hear the following:"mi-lui-cent-trente-cinqu. Is it near to the true pronunciation?

Comment: I'm from Paris, France. The `t` in *mille-sept-cents* and the `f` in *mille-neuf-cents* are both pronunced.

Comment: @AliTaghavi That is correct!

Comment: I have lived in France (Île de France) over 20 years and agree with Toto; this answer is wrong.

Comment: I have never anyone dropping the final consonant or "neuf" nor "sept" in "mille neuf cent" or "mille sept cent". Btw, those numbers are written without dashes.

Comment: @Evargalo I never heard "mille sep cent" or "mille neu cent" either. It is unclear from Domino's comment if he agrees or not about this. Note that the all dashes number spelling is following the 1990 orthography reform.

Comment: Based on everyone's comments, I have rephrased the answer to make it clearer that dropping the final consonant of other digits is specific to my accent.

Comment: It still a thing in France outside with 7 and 9: 400 *quatre-cents* [kat sɑ̃] (R usually dropped), 500 *cinq-cents [sɛ̃ sɑ̃] or [sɛ̃k sɑ̃], 600 *six-cents* X (S) always dropped [si sɑ̃], 800 *huit-cents* T always dropped [ɥi sɑ̃].